# SAP HANA users/roles privilige check

Tags: testing, roles, hana

Please help me with my case.

We have SAP HANA implemented in our company.

There were few custom roles created based on this doc provided by SAP:
http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/c02c2004-899d-3110-8488-b3ff8362bbf6?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&59180354403522.

We have few test users created with different roles assigned (like: **transport executor**, **transport manager**). What is the recommended way for testing if these roles are properly configured?
We were thinking about **XSUnit**, but we have no clue what checks should be performed in order to verify the privileges.

Is this approach proper?

Answer (score 0):

Checking privileges is a bit tricky.
Since the 'proof of the pudding is the eating' to properly test if your privilege setup is working as expected, you would need to

- set up a user
- set up your role
- assign the role to the user
- logon as or impersonate the user so that the role becomes the *current* role and therefore the *current* execution privilege setting
- try to do whatever the role allows --> this should obviously work
- try to do things that shouldn't be possible with the role --> here you should receive the right error messages
- tear down everything afterwards

There is nothing build into SAP HANA for that. And depending on what kind of privileges should be tested, it might be difficult to test all of them (dropping tables, deleting DBs, shutting down the system... all that is not easy to contain in a single unit test).

So, I'd recommend to use system views EFFECTIVE_PRIVILEGES and EFFECTIVE_ROLES instead and just check for operations that are allowed once the to be tested role has been granted.

- Lars